# ODE : $x(1-x)y''-xy'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me to solve this ODE:

### $$x(1-x)y''-xy'+y=0 \quad \forall x > 0$$

I noticed that $y_1=x$ was a particular solution of the EDO because,
$$x(1-x)(0)-x(1)+x=0$$
So, I began by searching another particular solution in the same style $y_2=C(x)x$.
$$ \begin{array} &y_2'=C'x+C \\
 y_2''=C''x+2C \end{array}$$
If we substitue this particular solution in the ODE, we get,
$$x(1-x)[C''x+2C']-x[C'x+C]+Cx=0$$
By organizing the coefficients,
$$x^2(1-x)C''+(2x(1-x)-x^2)C'+(-x+x)C=0$$
$$x(1-x)C''+(2-3x)C'=0$$
Now, we get an ODE of first order, by organizing the same terms,
$$\int \frac{1}{C'}\;dC'=\int \frac{3x-2}{x(1-x)} \;dx$$
$$\ln|C'|=-\ln|1-x|-2\ln|x|+K_1$$
$$C'(x)=\frac{K_2}{x^2(1-x)}$$ 
And, we integrate to find $C(x)$.
$$C(x)= K_2\left(-\frac{1}{x} -\ln|1-x| +\ln|x|\right) + K_3$$
And we find,
$$y_2(x)=K_2\left(x\ln\left|\frac{x}{1-x}\right|-1\right) + K_3x$$

Finally, we find the general solution by adding the two particular solutions :
$$y= Ax+B\left(K_2\left(x\ln\left|\frac{x}{1-x}\right|-1\right) + K_3x\right)$$

---

I'm not sure about my previous results. Do I have to keep the constants $K_2$ and $K_3$? Can you verify it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For what it's worth: [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x(1-x)y%27%27-xy%27%2By%3D0).

Comment: I know, I already saw that, but know that this answer isn't simplify and I will like to know where is my mistake and how to complete my answer.

Comment: Why not $$\int\frac{1}{C'}dC'=\int\frac{3x-2}{x(1-x)}dx\quad\Large{?}$$

Comment: That's right. Thanks. Ok, I will correct my answer. What can I do after that?

Answer (score 1):

You were doing good up to the line with $\int\frac1{C^{\prime}}dC^{\prime}$. At that point you dropped a factor of $x$. It should have read
$$\int\frac1{C^{\prime}}dC^{\prime}=\int\frac{3x-2}{x(1-x)}dx=\int\left(\frac{-2}x+\frac1{1-x}\right)dx$$
Then
$$\ln|C^{\prime}|=-2\ln|x|-\ln|1-x|+K_1$$
$$C^{\prime}=\frac{K_1}{x^2(1-x)}=K_2\left(\frac1{x^2}+\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}\right)$$
Then you can integrate to get to
$$C(x)=K_2\left(-\frac1x+\ln\left|\frac x{1-x}\right|\right)+K_3$$
So your general solution is
$$y(x)=xC(x)=K_2\left(-1+x\ln\left|\frac x{1-x}\right|\right)+K_3x$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = xu$ Then the equation reduces to

$$u''(x^2-x) - u'(2+x) = 0$$

Now let $v=u'$.  Then
$$ v = e^{\int \frac{2+x}{x^2-x}dx}$$

The integral is easy by partial fractions, and you then need to walk back down from $v$ to $u$ to $y$.

How did I guess $y=ux$ would work?

I didn't:  I started by trying $y=x^a u$.  That often helps for some value of $a$, and one chan choose $a$ after you wee what terms you would like to cancel or drop out.